# Azure ad ID token without login page or user interaction

Tags: nginx, azure-active-directory, token, azure-identity

I'm setting conditional authorisation with nginx api gateway. For this conditional authorisation i need to use ID token from Azure ad.
I need to get ID token as an implicit flow without user interaction. I'm thinking to user SP account for this flow. But finding difficulty to get ID token from azure AD without ui or user interaction..
Is there a way to get ID token without user to provide details..?

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT, i was able to get an Id Token using user credentials and interact.. i'm trying if there is way to get Id token without user interaction.

Comment: I tried with multiple other flow like '**Authorization code flow**' and **Open Id connect Signin** but in these as well it is interecting with user. 
Read several document as well found it is not possible to get the ID token without user interaction. The ID Token is **a security token granted by the OpenID Provider that contains information about an End-User**

Comment: Yes you are right. I think there is no way to get an Id token without user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the scenario and found that we can not get the ID Token without user interaction in implicit flow. You can watch this [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv8Qq.jpg) which I have reproduce

In the below Picture there is diagram for implicit flow how it works even in picture it shows it aks for user credential to get the ID token Access Token.

[image]

For more information you can refer this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)